# Is there a measure on $\mathbb{N}$? (What is the chance that a random integer from $\mathbb{N}$ is even?)

Tags: measure-theory

The more I study, I realize I really know nothing. *sigh*.
Now, here is my newest problem.
Picking up an integer at random from integer set $\mathbb{N}$.
What is the chance that the integer would be even? 
What is the chance that the integer would be odd?

Ok, I understand it - we can have a bijection and all - and show it is $\frac{1}{2}$ - in both the cases - but how? 
Can we introduce some measure for $\mathbb{N}$ - which shows that the set of even numbers $\mathbb{E}$ and set of odd numbers $\mathbb{O}$ are, sharing it 50-50?
Thanks to bijection we have all of them $\aleph_0$.

As usual, I am completely at lost here, please help.

Comment: So we do not have anything formal done for 1/2 to select a random even number from number set? :(

Comment: Not if (as usual) we ask for measures to be countably additive.

Comment: So there is NO other way than primitive counting? So half is --- simply intuition? Can you please add it as a solution so that I can accept it - and upvote it?

Comment: The "half" is not simply intuition, it is a precise (easy) technical result. Just happens not to use a measure.

Comment: But if you want only finitely additive (not countable additive) measure, there are such measures assigning a value to each subset of $\mathbb N$, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485443/finitely-additive-not-countably-additive-on-bbb-n) for details.

Comment: I love you guys, feel like in Heaven.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no (countably additive) probability measure on $\mathbb{N}$ that assigns equal weight to all points.

But we can easily get the following density result. Let $E(n)$ be the number of even natural numbers up to $n$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{E(n)}{n}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Man, seriously I do not know anything. But whats the point.

Comment: Umm...  The counting measure is countably additive measure on $\mathbb{N}$ that assigns the measure $1$ to all points.

Comment: @EricTowers, the counting measure is not a *probability* measure.

Comment: @Aditya:  The OP does not request a probability measure.

Comment: Let $\cal{A}(N)$ be sum of two ideals $I(O)$ and $I(E)$, where Let $I(O)$ be an algebra of subsets of the set $O(N)$ of odd natural numbers which are finite or whose complement in $O(N)$ is finite;

Answer (score 11):

As André Nicolas points out there is no countably additive probability measure on $\mathbb{N}$ which assigns equal measure to singletons.

The way people usually deal with such questions is by considering [natural density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_density).

> A subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is said to have **natural density** (or **asymptotic density**) $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1, \dots, n\}|}{n} = \alpha.$$

As André Nicolas also pointed out, the set of positive even integers has natural density $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Why can I not accept two answers? Both are awesome? :(

Comment: Because the accepted answer is supposed to be the best answer  according to the OP (i.e. you).

Comment: That is so not cool (and formal)! Arbitrary axiomatic assignment!

Comment: Well you can upvote answers you find useful, and I suggest you do (always, not just on your own questions), but accepting an answer is supposed to indicate that no other answers are required because the OP's question has been answered (by the accepted answer). To be fair, most of what I said was said by André Nicolas in the comments, so accepting his answer is totally OK with me.

Comment: Thanks and I always do it. It is just that given limited resource justice to individuals can not be done. :(

Answer (score 3):

You could look at the [counting measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure).  This usually leads to density argument:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and use the counting function $o(n) = \text{the number of odd numbers in [0,n]}$.  See that $\lim_{n \
\rightarrow \infty} \frac{o(n)}{n} = 1/2$.  Alternatively, see that $o(n) = n/2 + O(1)$.

For similar arguments (typically having a number theoretic or computer science flavor, and littered with [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)), see the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), and the [de Bruijn function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number#Distribution) (density of smooth integers).