# Is there uniform probability of natural number?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, uniform-distribution, natural-numbers

I know that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

But, I want to know if there is uniform probability in every subset of natural numbers.

It means,

1. every subset $A \subset \mathbb{N}$, $P(A)$ is well-defined, $0 \leq P(A) \leq 1$
2. $P( \emptyset )=0$, $P(\mathbb{N})=1$
3. $A=\sqcup A_i$ (disjoint union), $P(A) = P(A_1 )+...+P(A_n )$
4. $P(A+n)=P(A)$ (Here, $A+n = \{ a+n \in \mathbb{N} ~|~ a \in A\}$ )

Or is there a counter example that shows that such a uniform probability distribution does not exist?

Comment: There can't be a uniform probability on an infinite countable set.  Probability is countably additive.

Comment: @lulu I means 'similar' probability.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Either $P(n)$ is $0$ or it isn't (for some fixed natural number $n$).  If it is $0$, then countable additivity means that $P(\mathbb N)=0$.  If it is $>0$ then countable additivity means $P(\mathbb N)$ is infinite.  Neither are possible.

Comment: @lulu I think it's worth considering the non-countably additive similarity probabilities.

Comment: If you have some non-standard axiom system in mind, you need to tell us what it is.  We can hardly guess.

Comment: Note, though, that even with just finite additivity (as in your third assumption), if $P(1)=\epsilon>0$ then for sufficiently large $N$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^N P(i)>1$, another contradiction.  Note that your fourth assumption tells us that $P(i)=P(1)$ for all $i$.

Comment: In there, I think finite set has zero probability.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139577/discussion-between--and-lulu).

Comment: I think your question needs clarification.  Of course one could say that all finite sets have measure $0$, and all infinite sets have measure $1$.  So, sure.  It's possible.  See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485443/finitely-additive-not-countably-additive-on-bbb-n).  The Axiom of Choice no doubt lets you find others.

Comment: [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419290032U) is a possibly interesting paper on the subject.

Comment: the group of relative integers is amenable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group so there is a finitely additive measure on it

Comment: see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95954/how-to-construct-a-continuous-finite-additive-measure-on-the-natural-numbers and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485443/finitely-additive-not-countably-additive-on-bbb-n. this is definitely not an easy question

Comment: @lulu I upvoted your comment before finding an error with it (and I can't undo it now); in order to counteract my misplaced vote, I will point out what's wrong: the even and odd numbers are both infinite, and assigning 1 to each would lead to $P(\mathbb N)=2$.

Comment: @D.R.  you are correct.  There isn't such a simple way to define a finitely additive measure that assigns a measure to all sets.