# If $X$ is dicrete and $m$ satisfies probability axioms except $m(\bigcup_{n\in J}A_n)=\sum_{n\in J}m(A_n)$ for finite $J$, does countable sum hold?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-empty discrete set in the standard topology and $m:\mathcal{P}(X)\to[0,1]$ be a function satisfying all probability measure axioms except that countable summability for disjoint sets holds a priori only as a finite version, that $m\left(\bigcup_{n\in J}A_n\right) = \sum_{n\in J}m(A_n)$ for all finite index sets $J\subset\mathbb{N}$. Does $m$ then also satisfy the countable summability?

I suspect that if $|X| < \infty$, then the answer is yes for any countable union of non-empty disjoint sets of $X$ must cover $X$ after some index $K$. But other than that, I don't know. I have an ithcing that the answer is false, since proofs of this sort usually use at least the countable subadditivity of outer measures. But I am yet to produce or find a suitable counterexample.

Comment: What do you mean by "probability measure" axioms? . Do you mean the [measure axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition)? . Well if yes, then they are only three in number . Please define the properties you want $m$ to have. Many "properties" of probability measures are a consequence of countable additivity or sometimes they themselves imply countable additivity. So please edit your question.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204842/example-for-finitely-additive-but-not-countably-additive-probability-measure) post might be useful to you.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron The post you linked answers my question perfectly. Do you want to post it as a proper question so that I can close my question?

Comment: I have voted to close it as  a duplicate.